# scaling x coordinate for line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, linechart

I want to know how to get the x coordinates to start at 0.

```
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d, i){
            console.log(x(d)); //outputs 280.14285714285717 , 530, 378.57142857142856
            return x(d)
        })
        .y(function(d){
            return y(d)
        })
```

you could see in the comments that the console does not output 0 for the first output it's outputting 280.14285714285717.

here's my x variable `var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(d3.values(arr))]).range([0, width]);` I'm new to d3 but I would think this would take all my inputs starting at 0 to the max el of the `arr` array and scale it from 0 to the width of the svg that I assigned in a variable that you can see below. I guess it makes sense that `console.log(x(370))` would output to `280.14285714285717` but how to make that to 0 to make the line start on the y axis line? here are some necessary variables that I have,

```
var margin = {
        top : 30,
        right : 20,
        bottom : 30,
        left : 50
    },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 var arr =  [370, 700, 500];
```

I'll show you the full code that I'm dealing with that prompted this question but let me tell you what is wrong with the results. The line graph doesn't start at the left side (the y axis) and **I'm having problems getting the line *AND* the x ticks to spread out along the width of the graph**. I would appreciate your help with this.

```js
  var results = {
   "month1" :{
    "good" : 400,
    "bad" : 30
   },
   "month2" : {
    "good" : 800,
    "bad" : 100
   },"month3" :{
    "good" : 900,
    "bad" : 400
   }
  };
  var xLabels = d3.keys(results);
  var yLabels = ["bad", "good"];
  var arr = []
     
     for(var key in results){
      var obj = results[key];
      arr.push(obj.good - obj.bad);
  }

  var margin = {
   top : 30,
   right : 20,
   bottom : 30,
   left : 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var y1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(["bad", "good"])
   .rangePoints([height, 0])
  console.log(arr)
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,d3.max(d3.values(arr))]).range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(arr, function(a){
   return a;
  })]).range([height, 0])

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(arr.length).tickFormat(function(d, i){
   return xLabels[i]
  });

  var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1).orient("left")

  console.log(x(370))

  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d, i){
    console.log(x(d)); //outputs 280.14285714285717 , 530, 378.57142857142856
    return x(d)
   })
   .y(function(d){
    return y(d)
   })

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")


  svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").call(xAxis).attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis1)

  svg.append("path").attr("d", valueline(arr)).style({
    "fill": "none",
    "stroke": "red"
  }).classed("line", true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also I'm confused that if the above outputs were the x coordinates of the line graph why would they be out of order? shouldn't go from smaller to larger progressing through the width of the graph

Answer (score 0):

Your input domain goes from 0-700, and your output range goes from 0-530. So 0 would get mapped to 0 and 380 as you noticed gets mapped to ~280. If you want your minimum value (380) to get mapped to 0, you should set 380 as the start of your input domain, or more generally do this in case your input array changes:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(arr), d3.max(arr)])
    .range([0, width])
;
```

You only need d3.values for an associative array.

Comment: This is helpful but I still need help with my final requirements which are to make the line graph scale through the whole width of the graph AND have the tick marks scale the whole x axis. Right now the line just appears to be going up but that's not what the input demonstrates :  `
[370, 700, 500]` . It should go UP then UP again then back DOWN a little. I've been trying to do this the whole day. and the x axis part

Comment: I don't understand, if 500 is your x-value it should be plotted before 700. Unless these are your y-values, in which case you need to give them suitable x-values.

Comment: I don't understand either . I see this on the line `path.line` `d="M0,99L530,0L208.78787878787878,60" ` so it goes from  0 to  530 to  208. after I put in your suggestion.

Comment: That's right: 370 gets mapped to 0, 700 gets mapped to 530, and 500 gets mapped to ~208. Those are the new x-values after mapping. With the y-axis you are mapping in the opposite way: the input domain you have specified goes from 0 to 700 and your output range will go from height = 210 to 0. So 370 will get mapped to 99, 700 to 0 and 500 to 60, hence the path you're seeing. You're using the same array to create your x and y, but you're mapping them in different directions.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying. Im just going to tell you again what I want. The faster I get it the done the faster I'll close this question. If you want to help me that will be great. I just want a line graph that has the y axis tick label "good" at the top and "bad" on the bottom. The x axis ticks should be spread out  saying "1mo" "2mo" "3mo" . The line graph should represent how many people clicked good or bad over 3 mos. so if month 1  200 clicked good and 50 clicked bad. 1 month should have scaled 150 on the graph. If you don't want to do it I understand. that was my prob.

Comment: It sounds like all you need is something like this: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245. As for labeling the y-axis, what you want to do is explicitly specify the ticks and tick labels. You can read more about how to do that here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes